# Unable to write to WD external hard drive from centos 6.1 system

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive, centos, ntfs

I have a WD 2.5 T My passport ultra external USB drive. I attach it to centos 6.1 system on lenovo E430 laptop. The centos has the latest ntfs-3g packages.
The external drive is recognized and its contents displayed when I connect. However, when I try to write, the result of the operation is successful but no content seems to be written.

I then tried copying using a windows XP VM on the centos6.1 system and then copying from centos drive -> external hard drive via windows XP. That works but the transfer speed is of the order of a 16 - 20 bytes. I have > 2 G to copy and this will take more than a day.

How do I troubleshoot either of these problems.

I looked aroudn but could not find anything. Western digital site says that only windows and mac os are supported but given that centos supports NTFS which is what the drive is formatted with, I should be able to transfer.
Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the windows-and-macosx-only mantra, the usb drive should work fine with linux.
Just run

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
```

then

- connect the drive to machine
- mount it
- copy some data to it
- unmnount it

to get any technical info what's going on down there.